# Are these question correct? Is there any difference?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. Why you say yes?
> 2. Why you did say yes?
> 3. Why you said yes?
> 4. Why not say yes?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried to find the answers yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <s>Why you say yes?</s>

***not grammatical***

> Why you did say yes?

You are retrospectively asking why a person said "yes". The person must have already said "yes".

> <s>Why you said yes?</s>

***not grammatical***

> Why not say yes?

"Why not..." is used this way to *make a suggestion*. You are suggesting to someone that they should say "yes" to something, or to give their reasons for not saying it.

Answer (score 0):

> Why you say yes?
>
> Why you did say yes?
>
> Why you said yes?

These three are not correct. It should be:

> Why **did you** say yes?

The next one:

> Why not say yes?

This implies that the person has not already said yes, and you are asking them why they wouldn't. It could be written more verbosely as, for example:

> Why wouldn't you say yes?
>
> Why aren't you going to say yes?